# Trovare rispettivo livello CEFR delle parole

Tags: vocabulary

Ciao!
Sapete dove potrei incontrare parole italiane con il suo rispettivo livello CEFR?
Per esempio, il dizionario di Cambridge:
[image]

Comment: Ah, interessante. Posso dire che non è presente su nessuno dei principali dizionari monolingue usati in Italia (Treccani, Zingarelli, Devoto-Oli, De Mauro...). Probabilmente sul Cambridge che citi è presente perché l'inglese è molto più studiato all'estero rispetto all'italiano. Bisognerebbe cercare su dizionari pensati espressamente per stranieri che imparano l'italiano.